# How to know if a node is a closing tag </> in XML using xPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have to browse my XML file, and extract informations.

Is it possible to know when a tag is closed ?

I'm using xPath in XML/PHP, and working with a SimpleXMLElement and DOMDocument.

I would like to do something like this :

```
<ROOT>
    <TEST>
       Content
    </TEST>
</ROOT>

//PHP
if(/* something */ == </ROOT>)
    /* DO IT */
```

Comment: No way using xpath. Start from opening up to corresponding closing tag are considered one element in xpath.

Comment: Exist a solution in another language ?

Comment: Maybe you can approach the problem differently so you don't need to think sequentially like that. For sequential kind of reading XML, you may want to try [`XMLReader`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) by which you read node by node and [check if current `nodeType()` of type `XMLReader::END_ELEMENT`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060936/xml-end-element-is-read-twice-using-xmlreader-with-php)

Comment: I saw it on PHP Doc, and I think it could be a possibility to browse my file node by node, but the size of the document and the number of nodes is variable, no problem ?

Comment: Not a huge documentation about XMLReader :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `</ROOT>` string is not a separate node. The node is `ROOT` it can be serialized into a string as `<ROOT></ROOT>` or `<ROOT/>`. Tags (element nodes) are always closed, otherwise the XML would be invalid.

The short syntax has the same semantics as the full syntax. Here are several reasons for the full syntax. Child nodes are the most obvious, but compatibility is another.

You need to view the XML as a tree:

```
Element node: ROOT
  Element node: TEST
    Text node: "Content"
```

Some XPath expressions to get information about a node:

Has the node any child nodes:

`count(/ROOT/node()) > 0`

Has the node any child element nodes:

`count(/ROOT/*) > 0`

Has the node any child text nodes:

`count(/ROOT/text()) > 0`

Has the node any child text nodes (exclude whitespace nodes):

`count(/ROOT/text()[normalize-space(.) != '']) > 0`

The following example demonstrates node list and scalar value results:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ROOT>
    <TEST>
       Content
    </TEST>
</ROOT>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// if the expression returns a node list use foreach
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/ROOT') as $root) {
  // second argument is the context node
  // string() returns the text content of the first matched node
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(TEST)', $root));
}
```

Output:

```
string(20) "
       Content
    "
```

Comment: Thank you for explanations. I would like to know how to call an xPath function ? I tried $node->xpath(functionName($param)) and $node->functionName($param) but it seems not work

Answer (score 3):

You're confused between nodes and tags. An XML parser creates a tree structure representing a document. In this tree structure, each start-tag/end-tag pair results in a node in the tree, and the constructs between the start and end tag become the children of the node. XPath sees only nodes, it doesn't see tags.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use SaxParser which is event based and you can override endElement() method to achieve your result.

Comment: Yes, I've already used it during my studies, but now, this is a web project, I don't know if I can use Java for it then